# How to represent Graphs and charts in Xamarin Android

Tags: xamarin.android

I am new to Xamarin Android. Currently I am working on an app which needs to represent data in graphs and charts. I have seen previous post related to this topic. I am using Mono.Android v4.0 as Android SDK I installed is older.

Which is the best library that I can use for my purpose?

Comment: This guy makes some really cool charts using skia: https://blog.xamarin.com/microcharts-elegant-cross-platform-charts-for-any-app/ ... and more examples can be found here: https://github.com/aloisdeniel/Microcharts (hope it can be helpful)

Comment: @MathiasKirkegaard Thanks for the response. I have tried a sample with OxyPlot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several charting libraries available for Xamarin. Which one is the best depends on your requirements. All of them will draw charts. ;-)

Options to look into:

[MicroCharts](https://github.com/aloisdeniel/Microcharts)

[Oxyplot](https://oxyplot.github.io/)

[ShinobiControls](https://www.shinobicontrols.com/)

Comment: Yeah, I have tried OxyPlot and I can add it via nuget in my solution. So far I tried out it in a sample. Thanks for the help. :)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

If a simple time-series/line chart built with ASCII boxes is OK, you might want to check this lightweight (~20KB) Xamarin.Forms control:
https://github.com/maxim-saplin/TimeSeries-Xamarin